# Pointer as template argument - how to declare pointer to const inside template

Tags: c++, templates

When a pointer type is passed as argument to template parameter T, how do I declare a pointer to const type?
Both *const T* and *T const* become *const pointer to type*, whereas I need to declare *a pointer to const type*.

```
template<typename ValueType>
class TestClass {
public:
    void TestMethod(const ValueType x) {
        // When ValueType is int*,
        // type of x is int * const;
        // how do I declare x such that it is const int* ?
        std::cout<<x;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trait that does it.

```
template <typename T>
struct add_inner_const { using type = const T; };

template <typename T>
struct add_inner_const<T*> { using type = const T*; };

template <typename T>
using add_inner_const_t = typename add_inner_const<T>::type;

template<typename ValueType>
class TestClass {
public:
    void TestMethod(add_inner_const_t<ValueType> x) {
        // When ValueType is int*, x is const int*
        std::cout<<x;
    }
};
```

This will transform `int **` into `int * const *`, if you instead want that to be `const int **`, then you need a different specialisation

```
template <typename T>
struct add_inner_const<T*> { using type = add_inner_const_t<T>*; };
```

Comment: Thanks! Do we have one readily available in  std traits in C++1x? I couldn't find one. and there is add_const thats not the *inner* const.

Comment: No, that's why I wrote it out

Comment: Alternatively in C++14 `typename std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>, std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>, T>`. The versions without the `_t` suffix can be used in C++11.